# How to read and write a 3D array from text file using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d

I'm currently making a program for school which involves  a booking system for seats, and I'm trying to implement a system where seats are saved after every run of the program, and as soon as the program opens again, the current seats taken or available are shown.

Here is my code currently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int seats[6][23], ticket_count, h, l;
    char column;
    column = 'A';

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++){

            seats[i][j] = 0;

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << column << " ";
        column++;
        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++){

            cout << seats[i][j];
            cout << " ";

        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nEnter number of tickets to purchase: ";
    cin >> ticket_count;

    if (ticket_count > 23)
    {
        cout << "You can only purchase a maximum of 23 tickets.\n";
    }
    else if (ticket_count < 1)
    {
        cout << "You have to buy a minimum of 1 ticket.\n";
    }
    else
    {

        for (int q = 0; q < ticket_count; q++)
        {

            cout << "Ticket " << q + 1 << endl;
            cout << "Row (1,2,3,4,5,6): ";
            cin >> h;
            cout << "Seat (1-23): ";
            cin >> l;
            h = h - 1;
            l = l - 1;
            seats[h][l] = 1;
            column = 'A';

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            cout << column << " ";
            column++;
            for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++){

                cout << seats[i][j];
                cout << " ";

            }

            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("seats.txt");
    myfile << seats;
    myfile.close();
    return 0;

}`
```

However, when I open the text file, it gives me a random hexadecimal string. I could really use some assistance. Thank you!

Comment: *it gives me a random hexadecimal string* This is because you are writing the value of a pointer to your file. Use a loop to iterate the array and write each element one by one. Also where is the 3D array? I don't think you can imagine that.

Comment: @DeiDei The 3D array is written here:

int seats[6][23]

And I will try using a loop to write each element. Thank you!

Comment: `int seats[6][23];` is a 2D array :) `int seats[n]` is 1D, `int seats[n][m][o];` is 3D.

Comment: @DeiDei Oh my goodness, I can't believe I made that mistake! Thank you so much.

Does the loop method still apply for a 2D array? Like, in which I have to use a for loop to write each element one by one to the text file?